# How does the principal value affects to the limit here?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

In [Córdoba and Gancedo - Contour dynamics of incompressible 3-D fluids in a porous medium with different densities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225499707_Contour_Dynamics_of_Incompressible_3-D_Fluids_in_a_Porous_Medium_with_Different_Densities) (page 4) I read that if
$$ v (x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=-\frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{4\pi} \operatorname{PV}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{(y_1,y_2,\nabla f(x-y,t)\cdot y)}{[\lvert y\rvert^2 + (x_3 - f(x-y,t)^2)]^{3/2}}\ dy$$ 
and for $\varepsilon $ positive and $x=(x_1,x_2)$, we define
$$ v^1(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) =\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}  v\bigl(x_1-\varepsilon \partial_{x_1} f(x,t) , x_2 - \varepsilon \partial_{x_2} f (x,t), f(x,t) + \varepsilon , t\bigr),$$
then they say
\begin{align*}
v^1(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) ={} & v(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) \\
& {}+ \frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{2}\frac{\partial_{x_1} f(x,t)(1,0,\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))}{1+(\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))^2 +(\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))^2 } \\
& {}+  \frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{2}\frac{\partial_{x_2} f(x,t)(0,1,\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))}{1+(\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))^2 +(\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))^2 }.
\end{align*}

I don't understand how they get that expression for $v^1$. In other words, my question is **how does PV affects to computing the limit?** 
I asked this question some time ago, but I got no answers, that is why I decided to try one more time.

Please, any help or idea is welcome.